# Find and Replace/Insert 'CR', del Space wherever a user Clicks in a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

#### Short Version

In MS Word, is there a way to insert some text and remove some(simultaneously) at the point of blinking cursor or wherever a user clicks repeatedly.
This (Insertion/Deletion) can be achieved in the following ways:

1. Mouse click
2. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>) + Mouse click
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Mouse click + (Any Key)

#### Long Version

I have text copied from various sources in different word files which I want to format in a particular style so as to match a given layout. Basically the text needs to be broken down into new lines/paragraphs at specific places which is given in the instructions. Instead of having to press 'Enter' and then remove/delete spaces at every line, I wish to do that with just one click per line using macro.

These files could be 500+ in number, so modifying all in one go using Macros is the preferred way.(Although I find it impossible when the point of insertion of 'Enter' can only be done manually on each file.) I have used Macros to achieve 90% of that however need one last step where a Macro can do the following:

1. Where ever the user clicks on the page, all space(regular, non-breaking space, white-space) until the next printed character is deleted.
2. An 'Enter' or Carriage-Return is inserted, so that the text moves to the next line.
   Steps 1 and 2 are repeated at every click the user makes on the text.

**Example Text**

> This is an example, of my text, which I need to split up, into different lines.

**Expected Text**

> This is an example, of my text,
> which I need to split up,
> into different lines.

Notice that as 'Enter' is pressed at the end of these lines although they come in next line but usually a space character is there in front of those lines. Another approach is to click, delete the required spaces until the next character and then hit enter. I want either of these to be done automatically with just a mouse click or a minimum of key+mouse combo.
Something like Find ^w and Replace with ^p running at every place a user clicks, but with Macros.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You would do better to use an example that isn't religious material.  It's unnecessary and I have replaced with a non-religious example.  This site has members from all over the world, and all backgrounds, let's keep it neutral.

Comment: Cross-posted at: www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/38664-find-replace-insert-cr-delete-leading-spaces.html
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Also cross-posted at: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?62415-Find-and-Replace-Insert-CR-del-Space-where-ever-a-user-Clicks-in-a-Word-document

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Would keep this in mind. Actually new to the forums. This is my second question in any forums till now. Also read about cross-posting, which I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be possible by defining a shortcut to your macro. So you would need to click at a position and use your shortcut to run the macro.

Eg. Add this to a module in your document

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteSpacesAndInsertEnter()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Selection.SetRange Selection.Start, Selection.Start + 1
    If Asc(Selection.Text) = 32 Or Asc(Selection.Text) = 160 Then
        Do While Asc(Selection.Text) = 32 Or Asc(Selection.Text) = 160
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            Selection.TypeBackspace
            Selection.SetRange Selection.Start, Selection.Start + 1
        Loop
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and [assign a shortcut](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-9a92343e-a781-4d5a-92f1-0f32e3ba5b4d) to it.

It deletes all spaces & non breaking spaces right from the current cursor position and then inserts an enter.

Comment: Bingo! -- Your answer worked for me with a little modification. Thanks a lot. Here's what I had to deal with and how your answer fitted as a better alternative. I don't know how I make this line appear on the next line, pressing Enter here would simply post my comment. So, please forgive, if I am missing something here. As far as the anwer, I will post that separately as an answer, if that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier, I thought of using Find and Replace at the place of cursor, Finding ^w and Replacing with ^p but this required me to Constantly lift the shortcut keys I assigned with my macro, otherwise it would just break the complete text at every word into paragraphs. Just pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click would highlight the text between cursor and mouse click. All in all, I had to press (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), move the cursor to the new point using Click, AGAIN press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Thus lifting 3 fingers for every change, making it impractical.

Pᴇʜ Macro helped
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+Click still doesn't work seamlessly. Works in 3 steps repeating.
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+Click worked almost flawlessly, with just one step repeating.

Applying this macro, even if I keep <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>(my shortcut) pressed all the time, simply clicking at the desired place does my job. Although <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Click anywhere in Word 2007 brings up a Research Window which updates as the text is clicked but in no way interferes with the job being done.

Thanks a lot everyone and especially P for all your help, really appreciate it.
Cheers